# Remove validation data from train dataset

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, train-test-split, pytorch-dataloader

I have my validation and train dataset  and I am trying to remove the validation dataset that exists in the train dataset and create a new subset.

```
val_data = data from a previous experiment
train_data = current training data
new_data = data from train_data the does not include val_data
```

I am trying to get the new_data
Please how do I go about it?

**NOTE**: I am not using train test to generate the validation dataset because it was already generated beforehand